# tar/tar.bz2 a file from a different directory

Tags: bash, shell, tar

Lets say I am currently in the folder

```
 /home/user1234
```

Next, there is a file

```
 /home/user1234/files/mylog.log
```

From the /home/user1234 folder I would like to tar.bz2 mylog.log . What I have done was run the command

```
 tar cjf /home/user1234/files/mylog.log.tar.bz2 /home/user1234/files/mylog.log
```

This works however in the tar.bz2 file the compressed file is under its fully qualified path. I would like the compressed file to be in the 'root' of the tar.bz2.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've been looking at the -C option you can pass to tar but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tar cjf /home/user1234/files/mylog.log.tar.bz2 -C /home/user1234/files/ mylog.log
```

The `-C` essentially "changes" to that directory before compressing/decompressing the list of files (denoted by `mylog.log`).

Comment: That worked.  The tar is actually running from a script.  I was using -C but there was actually a further syntax error that my script was swallowing.  Thanks for your help.

For some reason I can't accept your answer. I will try again later.